# How to make a sticky footer in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the current situation of my theme:

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMjF6/156/). I don't want a `fixed` footer, and I don't want a sticky footer with `position absolute` , I just want to fill the horrible section with footer color , I think that `display:table-row` will do the trick, but don't know how to use it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Nah, you might want to take a look at flexbox

Comment: can you tell me how ? and is that supported in IE ?

Comment: Here is a very clean example: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ and here the support http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple structure of CSS `table` + `table-row`.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
header, main, footer {
    display: table-row;
}
header {background: pink;}
footer {background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

And set `height:100%` to one of the section if you want it to get maximum height available.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
header, main, footer {
    display: table-row;
}
main {
    height: 100%;
}
header {background: pink;}
footer {background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: that's the tricky way , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
.footer{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/GMjF6/160/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of would be to make a content container and give it a background color, then set the `body` color to the same as the footer like:

```
body {
    background:#0F0;
}
#header {
    background:#F00;
}
#container {
    background:#FFF;
}
#footer {
    background:#0F0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w01L939/)

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
```

to .footer

and

```
position: relative;
  padding-bottom: (n)px;
```

to body

***change (n) to the height of the footer***

```css
body {
  position: relative;
 margin:0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;

  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer{

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:100px;
width:100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<html><body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>


<div class="footer">text</div>
</body></html>
```